# How to zoom to the pointer in a google map

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map in an iframe in which, I am passing the longitude and latitude.

What I want is,

```
I want show the map zoomed to the pointer corresponding to the longitude 
and latitude given.
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sCZSL/)

In the given fiddle, user have to scroll the map to right, to see the marker. Instead I want to show the marker to the user, when the map loads with better zoom.

I will have similar maps like this with different longitude and latitude in different pages. I want to apply this all those maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "ll" parameter is the one centering the map. If you give it the same value as the "q" parameter, your map will be centered on that point.

```
https://maps.google.co.in/maps?[]...q=38.89205,+1.35275&amp;
[...]ll=38.89205,+1.35275&amp;output=embed"
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D4Y4r/

If you wish to zoom in, you can increase the value of the "z" parameter.

Quick edit: this page might provide you some insight on the URL parameters http://asnsblues.blogspot.in/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html